# Persistent connection when iOS app is in the background/terminated?

Tags: ios, swift, post, request

I'm new to Swift and iOS app development, and my boss wants me to fix the iOS app. The user has an option to start listening for events from someplace (using alamofire's `AF.streamRequest`), and then when it receives a response from that place he wants the app to create a new api request and send that out (based on the response).

The way the code is implemented, the app stops listening as soon as it goes into the background or is terminated. Sometimes when the user comes back into the app - after it was in the background but not terminated - the app will receive the missing events, other times it errors out and the stream request stops entirely.

Is there a way to make a persistent connection work on an ios app even when the app is in the background or terminated?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: There's no way to keep a connection alive when the app is terminated. As I have understood your task, a reliable solution may utilising Push Notifications. But this approaches the task from a totally different angle than the existing one and is not meant as a quick fix for your existing problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the app is terminated by user there is no way to wake up your app again.
Running your app in background is only possible for some specific tasks like play music, ...

Take a look at the documentation: [Handle Background Events](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/about_the_background_execution_sequence)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll let my boss know it isn't possible.